# Check memory usage while creating objects in a loop?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I was trying to check the memory_get_peak_usage() method, I try to create a objects dynamically inside a for loop, and tried to print the memory used by my php script. here is the code :-

```
$objArr = array();
for( $i=1; $i<=100; $i++ ){
 echo "creating employee == " . memory_get_peak_usage()/1024 . " Kbs\n";
 $objArr[$i] = new CEmployee();
}
exit;
```

And here is the result that confused me :-

```
creating employee == 4156.84375 Kbs
creating employee == 6619.640625 Kbs
creating employee == 6619.640625 Kbs
creating employee == 6619.640625 Kbs
...
...(up to 40 lines from 2nd line same result as above and then from 41 line changed)

creating employee == 6623.5546875 Kbs
creating employee == 6631.234375 Kbs
creating employee == 6638.9140625 Kbs
creating employee == 6646.59375 Kbs
creating employee == 6654.2734375 Kbs
creating employee == 6661.953125 Kbs
creating employee == 6669.6328125 Kbs
creating employee == 6677.3125 Kbs
creating employee == 6684.9921875 Kbs
....
....
```

I am not getting how php is allocating memory to the objects. I am running the script on command line interface on windows 7

UPDATED CODE:-

```
gc_collect_cycles();
for( $i=1; $i<=100; $i++ ){
echo "creating employee == " . memory_get_usage()/1024 . " Kbs\n";
$objArr[$i] = new CEmployee();
    $objArr[$i]->setEmployeeNumber($i);
}exit;
```

Comment: I think PHP pre-allocates more memory than it needs to be more flexible, I think that's how most of the scripting languages work.
Just a guess.
And if it reaches that point it then will start to get more memory

Comment: @daemonfire300 I think this may be the case.. but can u please provide me with some reference or documentation

Comment: This is a simple php script with out using a framwork

Comment: Back to my original assumption. It's only a thesis, I tried to explain why this could happen.
But as it comes often to high-level language features such as memory management you are pretty handicapped with languages such as PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see by this it does increase memory usage:

http://codepad.org/RApsrlXh

However you might have data ready for garbage collection, hence when you create a new `CEmployee` it might be using that space.

Try running `gc_collect_cycles()` before your loop to and use `memory_get_usage()` to get a more accurate reading.

Comment: Even thought if i set some value to each object like $objArr[$i]->setTest($i); results the same output.. I can access any of the objects from the arry after the output..then how can that be garbage collected

Comment: @ShowketBhat, I was saying that other objects, not the ones in your loop can be collected. Did you try the `gc_collect_cycles()` and `memory_get_usage()` like I said in the answer?

Comment: Yes i did that, and i got the result (in bytes) 4199384, 6396080, 6404392, 6412688. The ist object took almost 2 kbs, and then other objects took only 0.1 kb. what can be the problem

Comment: Please have a look to the updated code and the result is as i last commented